# How can I trigger Vue event from jquery?

Tags: vue.js

How can I trigger Vue event from jquery? I have

`<input type='text' v-on='keypress: doSomthing()' id='demo'>` .

How can I trigger this event outside of vue .. using jquery? I thought I can do

```
$('#demo').trigger('keypress')`
```

... but it doesnt trigger the event. It does nothing. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue is hooking native events. jQuery is generating events in a layer above native events. See this for more information on how to use `document.createEvent` to create and dispatch native events:

https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/

There's a good example here: [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Comment: Thanks a lot. jquery.simulate.js really did the trick. I can have <input id='x' v-on"keypress: doSomething()"> and call it using $('#x').simulate('keypress')